# How can I create url-friendly Id for AWS Cognito users?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I am developing the serverless application with AWS Cognito, DynamoDB and Lambda.
I need some user-friendly ids for URL. 
Is it possible to generate a number only ids with Cognito User Pool? If not what is the best way to generate it manually in lambda?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, Cognito only generates UUID format ID, you can get the user ID from JWT, no need put it in the URL.

If you insist on the numbers user ID, you could create a mapping table in the DynamoDB or RDS.